# Does tensorflow pick samples from a dataset randomly or sequentially when training?

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow

I have a dataset which consists of more than 10000 images. But similar images are grouped together. I mean first 50 images are very alike then the next 50 images are different(not as much similar as the first ones. I am talking about guns specifically) than the first 50 but they are similar between each other. If I choose a batch size of 50, will it lead to worse results? Or It picks random subsets of the dataset to train at a time?

I am new at deep learning if the answer is obvious sorry.

Comment: For a better answer, please provide those lines of code that configure and consume the batches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the site! My understanding is that it does it sequentially. It's usually a good idea to shuffle your dataframe as a pre-processing step and then train on that.